# Camel Loadbalancer CircuitBreaker is not working as expected

Tags: apache-camel

We are trying to implement circuit breaker pattern in our product.
    I tried to implement it and observed like if i give threshold value as '0' it is working fine.but any value >0 it simply waits for 2 sec and allowing request to communicate external rest services.

I tried below simple example where timer component is triggering messages for every 1 sec and in my processor i wrote logic like it will throw MyCustomException for 3 times, then circuit breaker will come to open state amd it should wait wait for 10sec as i read in camel document.but it is simply blocking request for 2 sec and then allowing request to process.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class CamelHttp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("timer://simpleTimer?period=1000")
                    .setBody(simple("Hello from timer at ${header.firedTime}"))
                    .loadBalance()
                    .circuitBreaker(2, 10000, MyCustomException.class)                       
                    .process(new MyProcessor())
                    .to("mock:result");
            }
        });         
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

I am just stuck at this point.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you at least spend some time to format your code example so its readable for people that may want to help you. eg if you dont show any effort yourself, then others may not even bother helping you.

Comment: Hi Claus, thanks for your feed back and sorry for inconvenience. I edited code and saved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved when I update my camel-core version from 2.15.0 to 2.16.0.

Now it is working as expected.

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer - it's what solved it for the OP.